# Heroku nodejs Procfile never picked up

Tags: node.js, heroku, angular5, angular-universal

It seems that my nodejs application is never deploying on Heroku. While my build successfully completes with the following message:

```
[154] ./server.ts 2.1 kB {0} [built]
[238] ./src 160 bytes {0} [built]
[244] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
[259] ./dist/server/main.bundle.js 76.1 kB {0} [built]
+ 301 hidden modules
Node server listening on http://localhost:5000
```

I'm only just seeing Heroku's Blank app:

[image: Heroku's blank app]

Other symptoms:

My builds never end:
[image: never-ending build]

And no dynos are being instantiated:
[image]

This is despite the fact that I'm providing a `Procfile`, like so:

```
web: npm start
```

See my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "vivonslagrasse-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "universal": "ng build --prod --aot && ng build --prod --app ssr --output-hashing=false && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors && node dist/server.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run universal"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.8",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^0.6.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^2.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.4.4-rc1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.7.4",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

Note that I need to run a node server since this is an angular universal app and the initial page's contents need to be server-generated.

EDIT: I'm adding my `server.ts` file (the generated `server.js` is too long to be reproduced here)

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;


// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const {provideModuleMap} = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), {req});
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Needless to say, this setup works perfectly on my development machine...

Your help will be highly appreciated. I already spent 2,5 hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use process.env.port in server.js to listen

```
const port = process.env.port || 5000;
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Share your server.js file

Comment: Just added my `server.ts`. The generated `dist/server.js` is too long (compiled by webpack)